# Review GREP and FIND results in Xemacs

Tags: grep, search, xemacs

I spend a lot of time searching code.  I really like grep and find, because of all the options available.  But it takes way too long to navigate the results.  I use xemacs and it takes 3 more commands to review each result.  Open the file, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd>, and type out the same thing I just grepped for.

After a search, I’m envisioning arrow keying through results, press enter and bam, have the file opened and be staring at the exact line of code listed.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Despite the down votes, I've often thought it would be good to be able to do this as well. Maybe develop your own 'grep' replacement to do what you want?

Comment: Probably because grep returns data to standard out.

Comment: http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6483/why-was-my-question-closed-or-down-voted/6490#6490

Comment: Does [M-x find-grep-dired](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Dired-and-Find.html#Dired-and-Find) do what you want?

Comment: May find more helpers at http://emacs.stackexchange.com/ .

Comment: I agree, it would have been better to migrate to the Emacs SE.

Comment: @Mark Plotnick - I tried out the find-grep-dired.   Good suggestion, but the buffer doesn’t show the line of code it matched, only filenames with a match.

Answer (score 1):

Within XEmacs, "M-x grep" (loaded from 'compile) runs grep in a sub-shell. The output is parsed by compile mode and you can middle-click on any match to go directly to the matching line in the appropriate file.

Although, I just learned today that "M-x igrep" (and "M-x igrep-find") is preferred to "M-x grep"

Am I missing something, that this answer hasn't come up in over 3 years?